# Problem binding data to controls in dynamically created wpf TabItem

Tags: wpf, tabitem, datatemplate

I am having problem putting data into controls on wpf TabItem.
I have defined several DataTemplates in xaml. Here is one of them:

`<Window.Resources>

...

<DataTemplate x:Key="memoTab">

<TextBox Name="memoTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" />

</DataTemplate>

...

</Window.Resources>`

I then create new tab in code behind as follows:

`TabItem tab = new TabItem();

tab.Header = "Memo";

tab.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("memoTab");

tab.ApplyTemplate();

System.Windows.Controls.TextBox tb = (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)tab.Template.FindName("memoTextBox", tab);

if (tb != null) tb.DataContext = memo; //string memo is created earlier as linq query

tabControl.Items.Add(tab); //tabControl is xaml defined`

The problem is that tb is always null, and therefore no data appears in the text box (the text box itself shows up in the tab and it is functional)

I do not use xaml to create tabs in tabControl (except the first one, which is not using DataTemplate and is fine) because they are meant to be added and removed by the user at run time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to get the `ContentPresenter` of the `TabItem`. You can reference the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) for this.

```
// Getting the ContentPresenter of tab
ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(tab);

// Finding textBox from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)myDataTemplate.FindName("memoTextbox", myContentPresenter);
```

The method FindVisualChild...

```
private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where childItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is childItem)
            return (childItem)child;
        else
        {
            childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Just changing to ContentTemplate.FindName does not work - it gives exception:  This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied.

Comment: @vdmpal Edited answer, check out the link for the complete example, I replaced the vars with your types.

Comment: Hmm... when I tried this, ContentTemplate of ContentPresenter is always null. I even tried to postpone it by adding Loaded event and running this code there, but no difference.